# Using Breakpoint in Eclipse with counterclockwise debugger

Tags: eclipse, clojure

While everything is configured properly, clojure working fine with Eclipse, I am unable to add breakpoint to code. On right clicking in Text Editor's window there is no option as "toggle breakpoint" for debugging.

Comment: what do you mean by " *counterclockwise* debugger"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/issues/detail?id=288&start=100

I posted an issue to CCW bugtracker. 
It seems, latest version of the CCW plugin somehow forget about debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually indicative that Eclipse do not think that your source file corresponds to a class file that it knows of.

In other words, it has no idea that your code is actually code.

Comment: Since Clojure is configured properly, running and giving correct output then why doesn't he offering breakpoints while debugging?

Comment: That Eclipse can run a Clojure program is not the same as it has been configured properly to know more than that itself.  In other words, the configuration is not done yet.

Comment: If plugin for clojure isn't installed properly then how can it run the program?